# How to use Route Masking server side support in NextJS without install node Express?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, next.js

I have read this instruction and I see **NextJS** require install **ExpressJS** to support server side for **clean URL**.

https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/server-side-support-for-clean-urls/create-a-custom-server

I have a concern because my application is use **ASP.NET Core** as a server, so I don't want to create anything else as a server, so does anyone have another solution to make a support server side for clean URL?